# what's the advantage to use "import static"?

Tags: java

What's the good point to use "import static"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general you should use static imports **[very sparingly](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)**.

One of the few places that they make a lot of sense is in your unit tests:

```
import static junit.framework.Assert.*;
```

Static imports were added to Java to stop programmers from implementing the [Constant Interface Antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface).

Comment: Link also says: "Used appropriately, static import can make your program more readable, by removing the boilerplate of repetition of class names."

Comment: Of course they were added because they are sometimes useful, but using them too little will cause much less damage than using them too much.

Comment: They can do damage? Sounds a little exaggerated.

Answer (score 6):

It allows you to remove the class name from function calls for static methods, as described with examples in the documentation here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html